# Location a point using Euclidean and Manhattan distance

Tags: geometry

Please see the attached image, there are two persons.

[image]

Suppose person 1 walks from 1 to 2, person 1 always follows the Manhattan distance and person 2 walks from 1-3-2 and always follows the Euclidean distance. Suppose person 1 reaches the point 2 before person 1 and has to wait there. Is it possible for the two persons to meet simultaneously somewhere between points 2 and 4 (say they meet at $N_p$). The speed of person 2 is twice as that of one. I thought of formulating these equations and solving but could not understand handling the Euclidean and Manhattan distances.

\begin{equation}
    |c-a|+|d-b|+|x-c|+|y-d|=\frac{ \sqrt{(x-e)^2+(y-f)^2} + \sqrt{(e-a)^2+(f-b)^2}}{2} \label{eq:67}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    (y-d)(g-c)=(x-c)(h-d)\label{eq:68}
\end{equation}

Comment: As you have drawn it, both person 1's path is straight and the taxi-cab distance equals the Euclidean distance.

Comment: Yes, I have drawn straight lines. Let's just say the length between 1 and 2, and 2 and $N_p$ is calculated based on Manhattan distance. It's just it is represented as straight lines.

Comment: Does the person take the shortest path between two points (according to the distance measure he "follows")? It is unclear from your writeup, but you also seem to make the assumption that the speed is in terms of the specific distance measure followed by each person. If that is the case, then you are unnecessarily introducing all those variables. Just use the fact that if Euclidean distance between two points is $d$, then Manhattan distance is between $d$ and $\sqrt{2}d$. Assume Euclidean distance between points 1 & 2 is d and between points 2 &4 is h and go from there.

Comment: By the way, the shortest path according to Euclidean distance is unique, but the shortest path according to Manattan distance between two points is not unique if they are both not on x or y-axis.

Comment: @user625 Thank you. Since the Manhattan distance is not unique, now I feel it would not be possible to locate the point where these two persons will meet simultaneously, I feel it would depend on the choice of path of the person following manhattan distance. What do you think?

Comment: @Kim if the points 2 & 4 are both on x or y-axis, then person 2 will never catch up to person 1 due to the speed difference. If they are not on x or y-axis, then person 1 has to travel a maximum of $\sqrt{2}d$ in the same time that person 2 travels $d$. Since person 1's speed is twice of person 2, I don't think person 2 can catch up with person 1 even in this case.